# ng serve halts with question so script wont finish

Tags: angular

I run Angular in GitHub Codespaces.

I have script to setup my dev environment, e.g. starting the server + Angular.

The problem I am facing is that when I run `ng serve` it halts with the question:

`Would you like to enable autocompletion? This will set up your terminal so pressing TAB while typing Angular CLI commands will show possible options and autocomplete arguments.`

How can I configure Angular so that it runs `ng serve` in "silent mode"?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/24582

Comment: I cant find a solution in that issue.

Comment: you can supply a config argument to ng-serve. that issue describes how to supply a config which will prevent it from asking to enable autocompletion